# Why is this Prime Sieve only working up to a bit less than Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, primes, sieve

I found this code here on StackOverflow:

```
public static BitSet computePrimes(int limit) {
    final BitSet primes = new BitSet();
    primes.set(0, false);
    primes.set(1, false);
    primes.set(2, limit, true);
    for (int i = 0; i * i < limit; i++) {
        if (primes.get(i)) {
            for (int j = i * i; j < limit; j += i) {
                primes.clear(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

but I'm struggling to understand how to get it working above Integer.MAX_VALUE.

I know i have to use long, but what do I have to change (in the loops) in this method to get Primes from Integer.MAX_VALUE to 3037000499L, or is it even possible?

Comment: *but I'm struggling to understand how to get it working above Integer.MAX_VALUE.* You should struggle, because it is not possible. All the relevant methods of BitSet take `int` arguments for bit indexes, so you can't exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  You could write your own implementation of a bit set that accepts `long` arguments for bit indexes, and then your bit set could be as large as your implementation allows.

Comment: You could try this implementation of BitSet that uses `long` values as indexes: http://java-performance.info/bit-sets/

Comment: But here's the thing.  While the `long` implementation of `BitSet` will take you beyond 2^31, you will still run into an OOME limit at somewhere between 2 to 4 times the max heap size.  And that will (should!) be less than your RAM size.  If you want to go further, your algorithm will need to be smarter.

Comment: One option is to only hold odd numbers in your BitSet, which will effectively double the number of primes you can hold.  Beyond that you could use a segmented sieve, where you split the BitSet into smaller pieces, each piece after the first starting above zero.

Comment: Note that 3037000499L is between 2\*\*31 and 2\*\*32. A simple implementation would be to use two BitSets, the first taking indices between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE inclusive, and the second from Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 through 3037000499L inclusive.